# How to undo DISPLAY export in linux?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, display

I have exported my X display to another computer using this command:

> export DISPLAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0.0

How can I undo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset DISPLAY to the original value. The details depend on your system but one of these should work:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```